# ANDROID - DOWNLOAD MANAGER

Tags: android, android-download-manager

download manager throw 'download unsuccessful' message below android 11.
if it's android 12 it's working.
how I get solution?

```
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            request.setMimeType(getMimeType(docName));
            request.setTitle(fileName);
            request.setDescription("Downloading attachment..");
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: Have you asked runtime permission for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: yes I ask run time permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: DownloadManager - trying to add a download functionality to my app. the problem is that when i execute the code to download a file nothing happen and after about 10 to 15 min a notification show up ( unsuccessful download ). But the url download in browser and android 12.

Comment: `unsuccessful' message below android 11. if it's android 12 it's working` And for Android 11?

Comment: In android 11 also not working.

Comment: and my url like,  http://document_view?doc_option=download&id=828&token=

Comment: @Maharaja have you found any solution? im facing the same thing

Comment: @TehleelMir Nothing man.

Comment: @Maharaja i was facing the issue because i was adding : in the file name i was tryinng to download, so for me the issue was in naming of the file

Comment: Thank you @TehleelMir ! I can't believe that this was the problem. Removing ":" from the file name made it work.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, if you want to use Download Manager without the Storage permission try using

```
String destination = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString() +
            "/" + nameOfFile;
Uri destinationUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(destination));
request.setDestinationUri(destinationUri);
```

instead of

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, nameOfFile);
```

and it works